# Unable to add platform android, throws unexpected token `{` in JSON error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, mobile, hybrid

When i try to add platform using "ionic cordova platform add android" it throws an error saying `Unexpected token } in JSON at position 2695`

Not sure why this issue is being thrown. I also tried adding other versions but nothing works.

I'm using these versions:

`Ionic: ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic) Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.0.1 @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4 @angular-devkit/schematics : 7.2.4 @angular/cli : 7.2.4 @ionic/angular-toolkit : 1.3.0 Cordova: cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1) Cordova Platforms : none Cordova Plugins : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total) System: NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node) npm : 6.9.0 OS : macOS Mojave Xcode : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001`

Comment: Below is the ionic info

Comment: Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.10.2 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework : @ionic/angular 4.0.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
@angular-devkit/schematics : 7.2.4
@angular/cli : 7.2.4
@ionic/angular-toolkit : 1.3.0

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
Cordova Platforms : none
Cordova Plugins : no whitelisted plugins (1 plugins total)

System:

NodeJS : v10.16.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm : 6.9.0
OS : macOS Mojave
Xcode : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001